# Can't remove unidentified horizontal hyperlink

Tags: jquery, html, css

**http://jsfiddle.net/fqnGT/**

in my fiddle above, my mouse cursor gets horizontal unidentified hyperlink to the right and left side of the button, I don't know why.

```
<a href="newgame.html"><div class="startnewgame">START NEW GAME</div></a>
```

[image]

Comment: why do you have a `div` inside `a`? `div` is a block level element.

Comment: give the hyperlink inside div and change its color would solve ur problem..

Comment: @codebreaker now the hover effect stopped working.

Comment: Like @Harry said, you shouldn't put a block element inside an inline one

Comment: @A.Wolff what should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: @codingfreak use any inline element as span or worst set as CSS rule: `a div {
    display:inline;
}`

Comment: @codingfreak: You can use `<span>` tag instead of a `<div>` as mentioned in one answer or if you wish to proceed with `div`, set it's `display` to `inline`. (I would strictly not recommend the latter)

Comment: @Harry when I set display inline, the hyperlink doesn't appear when I move mouse on the corner of blue button

Comment: @codingfreak: I will check that, but why would you not use `span`? any reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not allowed to use a `div` within an anchor tag. Use `span` instead - http://jsfiddle.net/fqnGT/1/

**Update:**
Set the `display: inline-block` for nested span - http://jsfiddle.net/fqnGT/8/

Comment: @coding freak: whoops, let's change it `inline-block` then :) -  http://jsfiddle.net/fqnGT/8/

Answer (score 3):

As per W3C standrads, you should not put `div` inside `a` tag. Proper way of doing is,

```
<div><a href="newgame.html" class="startnewgame">START NEW GAME</a></div>
```

Check out your demo, http://jsfiddle.net/fqnGT/2/

Comment: now the button doesn't show up any hyperlink when I hover my mouse over it.

Comment: the problem with demo, the hyperlink doesn't appear correctly when I hover my mouse around the blue. it just shows up only exactly when I hover on text itself but not div.

Comment: @codingfreak `div > a {
    display:block;
}`  Still valid and works as you expect: http://jsfiddle.net/fqnGT/9/

Comment: @codebreaker nope. it's not working when you move mouse around the blue button. This answer has 3 votes, although it has an error.

Comment: @codebreaker yes, my issue is solved by the other answer, however it's forbidden to get voted up by buddies, I flagged it for moderator investigation.

Comment: Hi this the best u wil get check out the fiddle below..http://jsfiddle.net/fqnGT/12/

Answer (score 0):

The most easy way

Edit

```
<a href="newgame.html" class="startnewgame">START NEW GAME</a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fqnGT/4/

Comment: move your mouse around the blue div, you will see hyperlink not working correctly :)

Answer (score 0):

add class to your link:

```
<a href="newgame.html" class="link">
```

add this:

```
a.link{
display: block;
float: left;
margin-left:100px;
}
```

and edit this:

```
.startnewgame {
width: 298px;
padding: 20px;
color: white;
background: blue;
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 32px;
font-weight: 900;
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fqnGT/3/  now I don'T have any button background check fiddle

Answer (score 0):

On `startnewgame` style class override the `display`

```
display: inherit
```

Edit: (on the original source with the div)

Comment: I edited the answer to format code blocks. If there are any concerns, please feel free to roll it back.

Answer (score 0):

You can change markup and css little bit:

### html markup:

```
<div class="startnewgame"> 
    <a href="newgame.html">START NEW GAME</a>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
.startnewgame {
     width: 298px;
     padding: 20px;
     margin-left: 100px;
     background: blue;
     font-family: Arial;
     font-size: 32px;
     font-weight: 900;
}
.startnewgame a {
     color: white;
}
.startnewgame a:hover {
     cursor: pointer;
     color: yellow;
}
```

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fqnGT/10/)

Comment: problem is that the hyperlink doesn't appear around the blue button. It only appears when I hover exactly on text and not button itself.

Comment: you can add two more attributes to `.startnewgame a{display:block; height:100%;}`